# What is wrong with this formula?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I tried this formula but for some reason, the result is 0 and not the sum of the cells from B7 to the row that I place the formula in.

the formula is:

`=SUM(CONCATENATE("B7:","B",ROW()))`

I want a sum of all the rows from B7 to the row that I place the formula in.

the CONCATENATE itself is working, the SUM is working (when inserted manually the range like =SUM(B7:B20)

They just do not work together and it gives me a result of 0 no matter the numbers present in column B

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are concatenating the A1 notation, the nested function CONCATENATE will return a String and SUM is trying to evaluate the sum of the String instead of the values of the Range.

You can pass the result of this concatenation to [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) in order to return to SUM the actual reference of the range of cells to be summed.

Full formula will look like this `=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B7:","B",ROW())))`.

Note: This formula won’t work if pasted on column B, because it’ll cause a circular reference.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing INDIRECT. use:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B7:B"&ROW()))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I wasn't aware of INDIRECT, this works for my purpose.